# Spring @ProperySource Not adding properties file to Environment

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 jars with a dependency:

1. clientKit.jar - contains a FeignClient.java and spring `@Configuration` file defining the `@Bean` for creating the FeignClient.java:

   ```
      @Configuration
      public class ConnectorConfig{

           @Value("${FeignClient.Host}")
           private String FeignClientHost;

           @Bean
           public FeignClientCls feignClientCls()
           {
               FeignClientCls connector = Feign.builder()
                       .target(FeignClientCls.class, feignClientnHost);

               return connector;
           }

       }
   ```
2. services.jar - contains logic. `@Inject feignClient.java` and uses `@PropertySource` to specify the .properties file containing `FeignClientHost`

Configuration File:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/C:/projects-path/app.properties")
public class AppConfig 
{

    @Inject
    ApplicationContext applicationContext; 

    // omitted code

}
```

Injecting the FeignClientCls (in services.jar)

```
public class CallFeignClient{

@Inject
protected FeignClientCls connector;

    public void execute(){
        connector.someMethod();
    }
}
```

and an external app.property file defining the host and port:

```
FeignClient.Host=https://localhost:8444
```

I'm getting below exception when spring starts:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'FeignClient.Host' in string value "${FeignClient.Host}"
```

I checked in debug and i see that Spring doesn't have the app.properties in the `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.propertySources` list when trying to obtain the value.

My question is - Can this be done and is this the correct way?
if so, why do i get the exception...

I have a similar code implemented in a different project and it works.

Thanks!